# Add text underneath iconbutton in appbar actions?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently trying to add the text ('Filter'), underneath an icon inside of the actions field within an AppBar.

Without any text being added underneath it. the action aligned exactly with the text and hamburger menu icon

Example: [image]

There are two issues I'm having:

1. When I add text, the filter icon moves up a little, I want the icon to be the same spot but text added understand.
2. I'm getting an overflow issue

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

```
    _appbarActions = [
      Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
          Text('Filter'),
        ],
      )
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippet code:

1. To remove the space between `IconButton` and `Text` use `Icon` only;
2. For the **overflow error** you can manage the icon size with text fontSize (styles);
3. For events wrap the column by `InkWell` widget

---

```
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Text(
                  'Filter',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                ),
                bottom: 5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

---

[image]

Comment: I do the see the filter text there now! But my issue is that the filter icon is now pushed up and both of the icon and text are centered. Where as I just want the text below the centered icon

Comment: @DanMossa see the updated answer using `Stack` widget.

Comment: Wow you're actually 200 iq